# Як перекласти "generic function"?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

Як перекладається "generic function" в програмуванні?

На вікі знайшов [це](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_function), але цього недостатньо для розуміння правильного перекладу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Підтримую [відповідь](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/932/4) про «generic» → **«узагальнення»**, «generic class/function/something» → **«узагальнений клас / узагальнена функція / узагальнене щось»**; це цілком очевидні переклади, що [використовуються на практиці](http://iwanoff.96.lt/cross_platform/labs/ua_02.htm) та [пропонуються навіть гугл-перекладачем](//translate.google.com.ua/#en/uk/generic+function) (хоч це й не ангумент).

Також існують іще такі варіанти:

- Microsoft Terminology Portal:

  - [«generic type» → «загальний тип»](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=generic+type&langID=uk-ua):

    > <sub>Definition: A class, interface, or structure whose definition has placeholders, called generic type parameters, for one or more types that are used in its member definitions. A user specifies real types (generic type arguments) for the type parameters whe-n creating an instance of a generic type.</sub>
    >
    > <sub>EdmComplexTypeAttribute and EdmEntityTypeAttribute can not be used on the generic type '…'. → EdmComplexTypeAttribute і EdmEntityTypeAttribute не можуть використовуватися в загальному типі "…". //У Microsoft SQL Server і Microsoft Power BI.</sub>
  - [«generic method» → «*універсальний метод*»](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=generic+method&langID=uk-ua):

    > Calling the CreateOrderedEnumerable generic method on the result of a LINQ to Entities query is not supported. → Виклик універсального методу CreateOrderedEnumerable на результаті LINQ до запиту сутностей не підтримується. //У Microsoft SQL Server і Microsoft Power BI.
- [Є. Мейнарович, М. Кратко «Англійсько-український словник з математики та інформатики» (2010)](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=generic&dicts=all&highlight=on):

  - «generic class» → «родови́й клас», «generic function» → «родова́ функція», «generic type» → «родови́й тип»;
  - також ще «generic function» → «характеристи́чна функція».

Але не підтримую ці варіанти, бо вони неочевидні і ніде не бачив їх на практиці.

Також не підтримую «generic function» → «шаблонна функція», бо «generic function» і «template function» у загальному випадку не одне й теж.

Comment: +1 за *родовий*. Мені самому одразу так здалось і без словника. Тобто функція для типів певного роду.

Comment: «тип-рід» має на увазі якийсь особливий тип як-от [людина-павук](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Людина-павук), тобто людина, але ще й павук? Ні, я мав на увазі, що *рід* - це як в біології. Зараз оновлю свою відповідь.

Answer (score 2):

Дозвольте спробувати дібрати переклад з розуміння того, про що йдеться.

В Java маємо Generics (**узагальнення**). Наприклад T — це узагальнення типу даних, тоді

```
List<T>
```

це колекція, яка може зберігати список об'єктів, наперед не знаючи який тип даних це буде.

Тоді generic function — **загальна, узагальнена функція** (в Java — метод), яка має вигляд:

```
<T> void addArrayToList(T[] array, List<T> c) {
    for (T object : array) {
        c.add(object);
    }
}
```

На етапі компіляції, компілятор підставить потрібний тип даних в місцях, де метод використовується.

Answer (score 1):

Відмінність від "звичайної" функції в тому, що "звичайна" функція вимагає конкретний тип і знає, які операції з ним можна робити, generic function вимагає, щоб тип з яким вона працюватиме підтримував певні операції, тобто вона ставить менші обмеження на тип.

Зі згаданого у відповіді Sasha [Англійсько-український словник з математики та інформатики 2010р. (Є. Мейнарович, М. Кратко)](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=generic&dicts=all&highlight=on):

> **function** = ['fʌŋkʃn] **1.** фу́нкція || функці́йний **2.** призна́чення **3.** ді́яти, функціюва́ти (функціонува́ти)
>       …
>
> - **generic ~** = родова́ (характеристи́чна) фу́нкція

Чому цей переклад мені видається найвдалішим, тому що

- йдеться про функцію яка може приймати типи, що відповідають певним вимогам/характеристикам;
- слово *узагальнений* незрозуміле в плані, в якому сенсі узагальнений? Код такої функції ніяк не узагальнюється. Та й більше воно б підійшло для перекладу *general function*.

Тут рід по аналогії з біологічною класифікацією, тільки тут ми класифікуємо типи, і функція може приймати типи певного класу/виду/роду/сімейства:
[image]

Comment: Які думки будуть стосовно: "параметризована функція"?

Comment: @OlexandrMatviienko річ у тім, що аргументи, що ми передаємо, це ж теж параметри, тобто є параметри типи і параметри значення, отже навіть не generic функція може буде параметризованою.

Comment: @Sasha Бувають родові ознаки чи родові помістя, а от виявляється є ще родові функції, тобто функції для саме цього роду. [Генеративні органи](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Генеративні_органи):)

Comment: @Sasha ну це завжди так, одні крокодили на північ,а інші червоні. Класифікації можуть бути різними, як-от програмісти за мовою програмування і програмісти за напрямком (бд, веб, графіка).

Comment: @Sasha *функція-рід* означає одразу і *фукнцію*, і *рід*, як-от *людина-павук*, а у нас функція для певного роду типів.

Comment: @Sasha, сама по собі функцію нічого не генерує, правда ж? Це компілятор генерує. І може не в усіх мовах відбувається генерація додаткового примірника - інстанціювання.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55204/discussion-between-sasha-and-yola).